# Amazon SQS Content-Based Router

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Is there a Content-Based Router for route the request or reply to the appropriate Consumer or Provider?

So that Message routers forward incoming messages to different output channels?

Comment: There is no automatic routing available with sqs right now